# tesseract ocr text: output difference between image_to_string and image_to_data

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am doing some OCR using tesseract to recognition text and numbers on a document. I used pytesseract as my python wrapper.

As a start, I just used image_to_string to see if my keywords are located inside my document. once found, I would use image_to_data to locate these keywords within the documents.

Here is where the problem lies. I am able to find the keywords using image_to_string but when I use image_to_data to convert the same input document, I could not locate the keywords in the verbose data.

Is this a bug or does tesseract OCR behave this way. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer about this? I am actually comparing the result of tesseract with -l eng --oem 3 --psm 11 using CLI to pytesseract.image_to_data(im, config='--psm 11 --oem 3 -l eng') and I can easily see that pytesseract is giving me different text as well as less relevant text. Doesn't pytesseract inherently use tesseract 4.0 ?

Comment: I was using tesseract 3.05. I had to set the hocr config to psm 6.

Comment: a) How did you read an image in Python, opencv or PIL? b) Did you change the resolution/DPI of the image for better OCR results? c) psm 6 gave you the best results?

Comment: My application was reading PDF documents so i use ghostscripts to read that with imagemagicks. There after with opencv and pil for some image preprocessing . Opencv is my preference as it has a lot of image processing algo already in built. Another alternative is scikit image. Psm controls how the text in the image are read and display in data frame. There was a certain format to the PDF and I had to output the results in a way that allows me correctly assign the detected text in columns that is sensible to me.

Comment: I also have a PDF to read from and that's where I am struggling. Tesseract OCR works well if the image is enlarged enough so currently I am opening the PDF in acrobat reader and zooming it in to 1600% and then manually taking a snapshot and then saving it as PNG to do text recognition. The saved PNG has good resolution to do almost accurate text detection. Can you please tell about your 1) PDF to PNG conversion and suggest some tool other than GS and IM as they are licensed? 2) what image preprocessing you did for good text detection?

Comment: Ghostscript and imagemagicks are open source so there is no restriction of using these tools. Gs to read and imagemagicks (Wand) to convert to image png or jpeg and then u can read in as image via PIL or opencv or skimage to do your regular image processing. In terms of image preprocessing there are many around for text ocr so just need to Google.

Comment: True, GS is open source but for its commercial usage story is entirely different. [Check here in the bottom](https://www.ghostscript.com/license.html) Yes, there are many image preprocessing tools for OCR are available but what I actually asked was what kind of processing you employed on your image?

Comment: Hey I am facing this same problem. What did you do for t hat issue?